# How many times can we upload binary to iTunes Connect after rejection from Apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Lately my app has been rejected by Apple twice. I want to know as to how many chances are left with me to upload the binary to iTunesConnect. And are there any consequences if they reject it again? 
And how many chances do we developers have in total to upload app to itunes connect after they are consecutively rejected from Apple.

Some poeple referred to this question as "OFF TOPIC" as it isnot a programming question. But uploading an app to appstore is a critical aspect of iOS Development. so it is here and i believe the tags in help center are totally appropriate.

Comment: "Lately my app has been rejected by Apple twice. I want to know as to how many chances are left with me to upload the binary to iTunesConnect" - Are you trying to upload the same binary? When app was rejected, you received feedback with reason of rejection. Fix the issues and only then submit your app again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not at all about programming

Comment: @mag_zbc i will be uploading a new binary with my new approaches to fix the issue. if they still reject it, how many more chances do i have to re-upload it by fixing issues?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Some poeple referred to this question as "OFF TOPIC" as it isnot a programming question. But uploading an app to appstore is a critical aspect of iOS Development. so it is here and i believe the tags in help center are totally appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no limit. You can submit your app as much times as you want. However if it still doesn't meet the standard then it will keep being rejected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: are you sure of this?

Comment: Of course! After all you payed for the developer program it's your right.

Comment: This is good question .. Same case with me also .Although it is not related to programming.    Thanks @ Mohammad Bashir Sidani to answer  your problem.

Comment: you're most welcome! :)

Comment: In my experience, there is now count limit, but after multiple re-submissions, each next review can take weeks :(